# Applying for visa of a foreign country in another foreign country (both EU countries) while being a citizen of non-EU country

Tags: visas, passports, europe

I was searching for an answer for a situation I have, but I failed to find an answer anywhere. I hope I'm asking this in a correct section.

I'm not asking for exact legal advice; I'd like to know what the procedure is and/or how something similar is done.

The main question is:

> How can a citizen of a non-EU country apply for a German D type visa while living and working in another EU country (for example Poland) on a long term visa?

The main point in that question is what is the correct procedure to apply for a visa and how do you identify yourself in the current EU country after you have submitted your passport with all the required documents for the visa application and are waiting for a decision?

What is the correct protocol to follow to be legally allowed in the current country while applying for a second country's visa?

What if for example a police officer stops you and asks for your documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the correct procedure to apply for a visa?

Details depend on the country in question, but the general procedure for visas holds: you submit an application at the consulate or embassy of the country whose visa you want.  If you live in Poland and want a German visa, you start by finding a German consulate in Poland, perhaps the consular section of the German embassy in Warsaw.

> How do you identify yourself in the current EU country after you have submitted your passport with all the required documents for the visa application and are waiting for a decision?

The details will depend on the country of residence, but most country's legal systems will recognize at some level that applying for a visa is a situation in which a foreigner may temporarily be unable to comply with identification requirements.

Some countries will issue a second passport to people who make frequent visa applications, so if the visa applicant is a citizen of such a country, it might be possible to avoid being without a passport.

Comment: The reality was that I was never asked to leave the passport. I submitted the documents and I was called again to get the visa stamped into the passport which took around 15-20 minutes.

Comment: @George perhaps you should make the question more specific by naming the countries, post this information as an answer, and accept it.